# смена ориентация экрана

Tags: android

есть 2 xml файла - activity_main и lend
я не понимаю как при смене ориентации экрана отобразить файл lend
всегда отображается activity_main при смене ориентации на горизонтальную он растягивается...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// setContentView(R.layout.lend);
// setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
textView1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Проверяем ориентацию экрана
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setContentView(R.layout.lend);

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

portrait layout должен лежать в папке `res/layout`. landscape layout должен лежать в `res/layout-land`. Оба файла должны иметь **одинаковые имена**, например `activity_main.xml`. Никакого кода для смены леяута добавлять ненужно. Это описано в [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html), прежде, чем задавать вопрос, вы **обязаны** ее прочитать